# Lubuntu 22.04 LTS pulseaduio corrupted after apt upgrade: how to troubleshoot?

Tags: apt, lubuntu, pulseaudio

I installed Lubuntu 22.04 LTS desktop environment in Xubuntu 22.04 LTS OS on my laptop, everything works good, so the OS shouldn't have problem.

Then I installed a Lubuntu 22.04 LTS OS to a Win11 desktop machine with 2 boots. Two problems appear:

1. this boot option page (example) is black without visiable texts

[image: this boot option page (example) is black without visiable texts]

2. the system works good with sound, but when I installed something, the `pulseaudio` control stucks with: `Establishing connection to pulseaudio please wait...`, and the volume icon in the bottom panel is red "!".

[image]

In order to find out the reason, I reinstalled the Lubuntu 22.04 LTS OS for a second time, same problem.

I'm guessing the `pulseaudio` failure is caused by `apt` activity, here is a complete history, would someone tell me what's the problem, and how to fix it?

```
Start-Date: 2022-09-20  16:34:15
Commandline: apt install fonts-wqy-microhei
Install: fonts-wqy-microhei:amd64 (0.2.0-beta-3.1)
End-Date: 2022-09-20  16:34:16

Start-Date: 2022-09-20  16:34:25
Commandline: apt install rhythmbox
Install: gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0:amd64 (1.20.3-0ubuntu1, automatic), libdmapsharing-3.0-2:amd64 (2.9.41-3build2, automatic), sgml-base:amd64 (1.30, automatic), libpeas-common:amd64 (1.32.0-1, automatic), yelp-xsl:amd64 (42.0-1, automatic), libgpod4:amd64 (0.8.3-16build2, automatic), xdg-desktop-portal-gtk:amd64 (1.14.0-1build1, automatic), libmanette-0.2-0:amd64 (0.2.6-3build1, automatic), gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 (2.36.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), rhythmbox-plugins:amd64 (3.4.4-5ubuntu1, automatic), gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (2.36.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), gir1.2-rb-3.0:amd64 (3.4.4-5ubuntu1, automatic), libgpod-common:amd64 (0.8.3-16build2, automatic), libsoup-gnome2.4-1:amd64 (2.74.2-3, automatic), gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0:amd64 (1.20.1-1, automatic), rhythmbox:amd64 (3.4.4-5ubuntu1), libsgutils2-2:amd64 (1.46-1build1, automatic), docbook-xml:amd64 (4.5-11, automatic), gir1.2-peas-1.0:amd64 (1.32.0-1, automatic), sgml-data:amd64 (2.0.11+nmu1, automatic), python3-mako:amd64 (1.1.3+ds1-2, automatic), libgrilo-0.3-0:amd64 (0.3.14-1build1, automatic), python3-markupsafe:amd64 (2.0.1-2build1, automatic), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.36.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar:amd64 (0.20.2-1, automatic), libyelp0:amd64 (42.1-1, automatic), yelp:amd64 (42.1-1, automatic), libtotem-plparser-common:amd64 (3.26.6-1build1, automatic), gir1.2-soup-2.4:amd64 (2.74.2-3, automatic), libpeas-1.0-0:amd64 (1.32.0-1, automatic), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.36.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), xml-core:amd64 (0.18+nmu1, automatic), gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64 (1.20.3-0ubuntu1, automatic), librhythmbox-core10:amd64 (3.4.4-5ubuntu1, automatic), xdg-dbus-proxy:amd64 (0.1.3-1, automatic), rhythmbox-data:amd64 (3.4.4-5ubuntu1, automatic), libtotem-plparser18:amd64 (3.26.6-1build1, automatic)
End-Date: 2022-09-20  16:34:34

Start-Date: 2022-09-20  16:34:38
Commandline: apt install pavucontrol
Install: libcanberra-gtk3-0:amd64 (0.30-10ubuntu1, automatic), libatkmm-1.6-1v5:amd64 (2.28.2-1build1, automatic), libcanberra-gtk3-module:amd64 (0.30-10ubuntu1, automatic), libcairomm-1.0-1v5:amd64 (1.12.2-4build3, automatic), pavucontrol:amd64 (5.0-2), libpangomm-1.4-1v5:amd64 (2.46.2-1, automatic), libglibmm-2.4-1v5:amd64 (2.66.2-2, automatic), libgtkmm-3.0-1v5:amd64 (3.24.5-1build1, automatic), libsigc++-2.0-0v5:amd64 (2.10.4-2ubuntu3, automatic)
End-Date: 2022-09-20  16:34:40

Start-Date: 2022-09-20  16:34:42
Commandline: apt install unrar
Install: unrar:amd64 (1:6.1.5-1)
End-Date: 2022-09-20  16:34:43

Start-Date: 2022-09-20  16:34:46
Commandline: apt install net-tools
Install: net-tools:amd64 (1.60+git20181103.0eebece-1ubuntu5)
End-Date: 2022-09-20  16:34:46

Start-Date: 2022-09-20  16:34:51
Commandline: apt install openssh-server
Install: ssh-import-id:amd64 (5.11-0ubuntu1, automatic), openssh-server:amd64 (1:8.9p1-3), openssh-sftp-server:amd64 (1:8.9p1-3, automatic), ncurses-term:amd64 (6.3-2, automatic)
End-Date: 2022-09-20  16:34:55

Start-Date: 2022-09-20  16:34:58
Commandline: apt install xiphos
Install: xiphos:amd64 (4.2.1+dfsg1-6build1), libbiblesync1.1:amd64 (2.1.0-1, automatic), libsword1.9.0:amd64 (1.9.0+dfsg-4build3, automatic), xiphos-data:amd64 (4.2.1+dfsg1-6build1, automatic), libsword-common:amd64 (1.9.0+dfsg-4build3, automatic)
End-Date: 2022-09-20  16:35:00

Start-Date: 2022-09-20  16:35:03
Commandline: apt install bibletime
Install: bibletime-data:amd64 (3.0.2-1, automatic), bibletime:amd64 (3.0.2-1)
End-Date: 2022-09-20  16:35:05

Start-Date: 2022-09-20  16:35:09
Commandline: apt install ristretto
Install: libxfce4util-bin:amd64 (4.16.0-1, automatic), libxfce4ui-common:amd64 (4.16.1-1, automatic), tumbler:amd64 (4.16.0-1, automatic), libxfce4ui-2-0:amd64 (4.16.1-1, automatic), tumbler-common:amd64 (4.16.0-1, automatic), libxfconf-0-3:amd64 (4.16.0-2, automatic), xfconf:amd64 (4.16.0-2, automatic), libtumbler-1-0:amd64 (4.16.0-1, automatic), libxfce4util7:amd64 (4.16.0-1, automatic), ristretto:amd64 (0.12.2-1), libxfce4util-common:amd64 (4.16.0-1, automatic)
End-Date: 2022-09-20  16:35:11

Start-Date: 2022-09-20  16:35:14
Commandline: apt install gnome-software
Install: gnome-software:amd64 (41.5-2ubuntu2), gir1.2-snapd-1:amd64 (1.60-0ubuntu1, automatic), gnome-software-common:amd64 (41.5-2ubuntu2, automatic), libgtk3-perl:amd64 (0.038-1, automatic), libmalcontent-0-0:amd64 (0.10.4-1, automatic), gnome-session-bin:amd64 (42.0-1ubuntu2, automatic), ubuntu-advantage-desktop-daemon:amd64 (1.9~22.04.1, automatic), libextutils-depends-perl:amd64 (0.8001-1, automatic), gnome-software-plugin-snap:amd64 (41.5-2ubuntu2, automatic), software-properties-gtk:amd64 (0.99.22.3, automatic), gir1.2-goa-1.0:amd64 (3.44.0-1ubuntu1, automatic), libcairo-gobject-perl:amd64 (1.005-3build1, automatic), libglib-object-introspection-perl:amd64 (0.049-1+build2, automatic), gnome-startup-applications:amd64 (42.0-1ubuntu2, automatic), libglib-perl:amd64 (3:1.329.3-2build1, automatic), libcairo-perl:amd64 (1.109-2build1, automatic), gnome-session-common:amd64 (42.0-1ubuntu2, automatic)
Upgrade: software-properties-qt:amd64 (0.99.22.2, 0.99.22.3), software-properties-common:amd64 (0.99.22.2, 0.99.22.3), python3-software-properties:amd64 (0.99.22.2, 0.99.22.3)
End-Date: 2022-09-20  16:35:25

Start-Date: 2022-09-20  16:35:36
Commandline: apt-get install -y python3-pip
Requested-By: chen (1000)
Install: libalgorithm-merge-perl:amd64 (0.08-3, automatic), manpages-dev:amd64 (5.10-1ubuntu1, automatic), g++-11:amd64 (11.2.0-19ubuntu1, automatic), gcc-11:amd64 (11.2.0-19ubuntu1, automatic), build-essential:amd64 (12.9ubuntu3, automatic), libctf-nobfd0:amd64 (2.38-3ubuntu1, automatic), libtsan0:amd64 (11.2.0-19ubuntu1, automatic), libpython3-dev:amd64 (3.10.4-0ubuntu2, automatic), g++:amd64 (4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1, automatic), gcc:amd64 (4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1, automatic), python3-lib2to3:amd64 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1, automatic), libalgorithm-diff-perl:amd64 (1.201-1, automatic), libbinutils:amd64 (2.38-3ubuntu1, automatic), libfakeroot:amd64 (1.28-1ubuntu1, automatic), binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu:amd64 (2.38-3ubuntu1, automatic), libcc1-0:amd64 (12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04, automatic), zlib1g-dev:amd64 (1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9.1, automatic), python3-wheel:amd64 (0.37.1-2, automatic), libfile-fcntllock-perl:amd64 (0.22-3build7, automatic), dpkg-dev:amd64 (1.21.1ubuntu2.1, automatic), libasan6:amd64 (11.2.0-19ubuntu1, automatic), libnsl-dev:amd64 (1.3.0-2build2, automatic), rpcsvc-proto:amd64 (1.4.2-0ubuntu6, automatic), libctf0:amd64 (2.38-3ubuntu1, automatic), lto-disabled-list:amd64 (24, automatic), python3-dev:amd64 (3.10.4-0ubuntu2, automatic), libcrypt-dev:amd64 (1:4.4.27-1, automatic), libpython3.10-dev:amd64 (3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1, automatic), binutils-common:amd64 (2.38-3ubuntu1, automatic), libitm1:amd64 (12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04, automatic), python3-pip:amd64 (22.0.2+dfsg-1), libdpkg-perl:amd64 (1.21.1ubuntu2.1, automatic), python3.10-dev:amd64 (3.10.4-3ubuntu0.1, automatic), libc-dev-bin:amd64 (2.35-0ubuntu3.1, automatic), libc-devtools:amd64 (2.35-0ubuntu3.1, automatic), python3-distutils:amd64 (3.10.4-0ubuntu1, automatic), libc6-dev:amd64 (2.35-0ubuntu3.1, automatic), libexpat1-dev:amd64 (2.4.7-1, automatic), libubsan1:amd64 (12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04, automatic), liblsan0:amd64 (12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04, automatic), libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl:amd64 (0.04-6build3, automatic), python3-setuptools:amd64 (59.6.0-1.2, automatic), libjs-sphinxdoc:amd64 (4.3.2-1, automatic), libjs-underscore:amd64 (1.13.2~dfsg-2, automatic), libtirpc-dev:amd64 (1.3.2-2ubuntu0.1, automatic), libgcc-11-dev:amd64 (11.2.0-19ubuntu1, automatic), libstdc++-11-dev:amd64 (11.2.0-19ubuntu1, automatic), binutils:amd64 (2.38-3ubuntu1, automatic), fakeroot:amd64 (1.28-1ubuntu1, automatic), libatomic1:amd64 (12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04, automatic), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.15.0-48.54, automatic)
Upgrade: libgomp1:amd64 (12-20220319-1ubuntu1, 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04), libgfortran5:amd64 (12-20220319-1ubuntu1, 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04), libquadmath0:amd64 (12-20220319-1ubuntu1, 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04), zlib1g:amd64 (1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9, 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu9.1), gcc-12-base:amd64 (12-20220319-1ubuntu1, 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04), libstdc++6:amd64 (12-20220319-1ubuntu1, 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04), libgcc-s1:amd64 (12-20220319-1ubuntu1, 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04)
End-Date: 2022-09-20  16:35:51

Start-Date: 2022-09-20  16:56:52
Commandline: apt remove --purge terminator
Requested-By: chen (1000)
Purge: terminator:amd64 (2.1.1-1)
End-Date: 2022-09-20  16:56:53

Start-Date: 2022-09-20  16:57:16
Commandline: apt remove --purge kcalc
Requested-By: chen (1000)
Purge: kcalc:amd64 (4:21.12.3-0ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2022-09-20  16:57:17

Start-Date: 2022-09-20  16:57:28
Commandline: apt remove --purge 2048-qt
Requested-By: chen (1000)
Purge: 2048-qt:amd64 (0.1.6-2build1)
End-Date: 2022-09-20  16:57:29

Start-Date: 2022-09-20  16:58:00
Commandline: apt upgrade
Requested-By: chen (1000)
Install: linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-48.54, automatic), linux-headers-5.15.0-48-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-48.54, automatic), linux-modules-5.15.0-48-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-48.54, automatic), linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-48-generic:amd64 (5.15.0-48.54, automatic), linux-headers-5.15.0-48:amd64 (5.15.0-48.54, automatic)
Upgrade: dmidecode:amd64 (3.3-3, 3.3-3ubuntu0.1), libpoppler-qt5-1:amd64 (22.02.0-2, 22.02.0-2ubuntu0.1), libcurl4:amd64 (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.3, 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.4), libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.3, 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.4), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin:amd64 (2.42.8+dfsg-1, 2.42.8+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1), python3-distupgrade:amd64 (1:22.04.13, 1:22.04.14), linux-headers-generic:amd64 (5.15.0.43.44, 5.15.0.48.48), apt:amd64 (2.4.6, 2.4.7), libnftables1:amd64 (1.0.2-1ubuntu2, 1.0.2-1ubuntu3), cryptsetup-bin:amd64 (2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1, 2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1.1), tzdata:amd64 (2022a-0ubuntu1, 2022c-0ubuntu0.22.04.0), xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu:amd64 (22.0.0-1build1, 22.0.0-1ubuntu0.1), libldap-common:amd64 (2.5.12+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libwayland-cursor0:amd64 (1.20.0-1, 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1), libqt5core5a:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1, 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2), qt5-gtk-platformtheme:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1, 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2), kde-config-updates:amd64 (5.24.4-0ubuntu1, 5.24.6-0ubuntu0.1), xxd:amd64 (2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2, 2:8.2.3995-1ubuntu2.1), gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:amd64 (2.42.8+dfsg-1, 2.42.8+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1), libapt-pkg6.0:amd64 (2.4.6, 2.4.7), xdg-desktop-portal-kde:amd64 (5.24.4-0ubuntu1, 5.24.6-0ubuntu0.1), libkf5su5:amd64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu1, 5.92.0-0ubuntu1.1), libwayland-server0:amd64 (1.20.0-1, 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1), libtiff5:amd64 (4.3.0-6, 4.3.0-6ubuntu0.1), libqt5network5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1, 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2), plasma-discover-common:amd64 (5.24.4-0ubuntu1, 5.24.6-0ubuntu0.1), libqt5concurrent5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1, 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2), libllvm13:amd64 (1:13.0.1-2ubuntu2, 1:13.0.1-2ubuntu2.1), libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0:amd64 (2.42.8+dfsg-1, 2.42.8+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1), libqt5dbus5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1, 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2), libpoppler-cpp0v5:amd64 (22.02.0-2, 22.02.0-2ubuntu0.1), libqt5test5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1, 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2), libldap-2.5-0:amd64 (2.5.12+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 2.5.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), linux-generic:amd64 (5.15.0.43.44, 5.15.0.48.48), libqt5widgets5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1, 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2), isc-dhcp-common:amd64 (4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.1, 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.2), poppler-utils:amd64 (22.02.0-2, 22.02.0-2ubuntu0.1), libkf5su-bin:amd64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu1, 5.92.0-0ubuntu1.1), libqt5gui5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1, 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2), plasma-discover-backend-snap:amd64 (5.24.4-0ubuntu1, 5.24.6-0ubuntu0.1), libqt5printsupport5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1, 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2), libpoppler-glib8:amd64 (22.02.0-2, 22.02.0-2ubuntu0.1), libqt5xml5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1, 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2), plasma-discover-backend-fwupd:amd64 (5.24.4-0ubuntu1, 5.24.6-0ubuntu0.1), isc-dhcp-client:amd64 (4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.1, 4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.2), libpoppler118:amd64 (22.02.0-2, 22.02.0-2ubuntu0.1), cryptsetup-initramfs:amd64 (2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1, 2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1.1), libqt5sql5:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1, 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2), libxslt1.1:amd64 (1.1.34-4build2, 1.1.34-4ubuntu0.22.04.1), linux-image-generic:amd64 (5.15.0.43.44, 5.15.0.48.48), libcryptsetup12:amd64 (2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1, 2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1.1), python3-jwt:amd64 (2.3.0-1ubuntu0.1, 2.3.0-1ubuntu0.2), linux-firmware:amd64 (20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.3, 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.5), kde-style-breeze:amd64 (4:5.24.4-0ubuntu1, 4:5.24.6-0ubuntu0.1), breeze-cursor-theme:amd64 (4:5.24.4-0ubuntu1, 4:5.24.6-0ubuntu0.1), cryptsetup:amd64 (2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1, 2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1.1), libwayland-egl1:amd64 (1.20.0-1, 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1), ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt:amd64 (1:22.04.13, 1:22.04.14), libkf5su-data:amd64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu1, 5.92.0-0ubuntu1.1), libkf5newstuffcore5:amd64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu1, 5.92.0-0ubuntu1.1), plasma-discover:amd64 (5.24.4-0ubuntu1, 5.24.6-0ubuntu0.1), xdg-utils:amd64 (1.1.3-4.1ubuntu1.22.04.1, 1.1.3-4.1ubuntu3~22.04.1), libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64 (5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1, 5.15.3+dfsg-2ubuntu0.2), apt-utils:amd64 (2.4.6, 2.4.7), thermald:amd64 (2.4.9-1, 2.4.9-1ubuntu0.1), ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:amd64 (1:22.04.13, 1:22.04.14), qml-module-org-kde-newstuff:amd64 (5.92.0-0ubuntu1, 5.92.0-0ubuntu1.1), ubuntu-advantage-tools:amd64 (27.9~22.04.1, 27.10.1~22.04.1), libwayland-client0:amd64 (1.20.0-1, 1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1), bluedevil:amd64 (4:5.24.4-0ubuntu1, 4:5.24.6-0ubuntu0.1), intel-microcode:amd64 (3.20220510.0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 3.20220809.0ubuntu0.22.04.1), libkworkspace5-5:amd64 (4:5.24.4-0ubuntu1, 4:5.24.6-0ubuntu0.1), nftables:amd64 (1.0.2-1ubuntu2, 1.0.2-1ubuntu3), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common:amd64 (2.42.8+dfsg-1, 2.42.8+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1)
End-Date: 2022-09-20  16:59:08

Start-Date: 2022-09-20  17:46:35
Commandline: apt autoremove
Requested-By: chen (1000)
Remove: libxcb-xtest0:amd64 (1.14-3ubuntu3), python3-ibus-1.0:amd64 (1.5.26-4), libegl1-mesa:amd64 (22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1), libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1), gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64 (1.5.26-4), dconf-cli:amd64 (0.40.0-3), libvte-2.91-common:amd64 (0.68.0-1), python3-psutil:amd64 (5.9.0-1build1), gir1.2-keybinder-3.0:amd64 (0.3.2-1.1), python3-configobj:amd64 (5.0.6-5), gir1.2-vte-2.91:amd64 (0.68.0-1), libvte-2.91-0:amd64 (0.68.0-1), libibus-1.0-5:amd64 (1.5.26-4), libkeybinder-3.0-0:amd64 (0.3.2-1.1)
End-Date: 2022-09-20  17:46:38
```

The `pulseaudio` problem appears after one reboot around 16:30-17:00.

```
chen@joy:~$ last reboot
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-43-generi Tue Sep 20 16:52   still running
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-43-generi Tue Sep 20 15:54 - 16:52  (00:57)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pulseaudio connection failure is caused by corruption of `.bashrc`. I set this file in WSL2 in odrder to enable audio output.
I rsynced this file to the new Lubuntu system by mistake. Just comment out this lines to fix the audio problem:

```
## QC (6/6/2022) for pulseaudio in WSL2
#https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5816#issuecomment-682242686
#export PULSE_SERVER=tcp:$(grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}');
```